# How to resolve 'no database instance for "mydb"' in Oracle Enterprise Manager?

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I've done a manual installation of the database from CLI (setting init.ora and other stuff), now I can connect to sqlplus as sysdba, but I have some issues and errors.

First of all if I tried to check the listener status, now I have no instance for the database I have created.

Before there was one instance (called with the database name "mydb", BLOCKED) but after rebooting the PC and connecting again to sqlplus, I try "lsnrctl status" and I have no instance for "mydb", there is only one instance "CTRExtProc".

Second thing, I can't connect to enterprise manager, on ports 1158 or 5500 (I tried telnetting the ports and they're not responding).

Comment: O/S?  You mentioned PC, so I'm guessing either Windows or Linux.  Which release?  (i.e. Win 7 Home, Ultimate, etc, RedHat Linux 5.7, Oracle Linux 6.5, etc,etc)

Comment: I'm using windows 8. A part of the problem could be related with the controlfiles that seems not to be created? One of the recurring error is ora00205, can't find controlfiles... Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3575921, are you creating the DB using the DBCA? Or are you creating it using the binary installer? Windows 8 64bit? Are you getting any errors during the installation? The Listener should be set up during the netca phase of the installer.